# Migrating PostgreSQL 9.5 to 10 - Foreign key, Primary key

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, postgresql-10

I am migrating my Postgresql 9.5 to Postgresql 10
I have also a Visual studio .net component (npgsql) integration that helps me to connect and to use Entity Framework with .NET.

I am forced to use partitioning too on two large (huge) tables
I noticed that there are no Foreign key or Primary key on partitioned tables on Postgresql 10.

This is a problem as my Visual Studio had the tables declared with several foreign keys and one primary key and I have to change all my code, are there any possible solutions or workarounds?

My concerns are on my code in c# that expects a primary key on all tables, without primary keys or foreign keys I am not sure the code will work.
In reality, I created my classes manually.
EF needs primary keys, or is my false belief?
Plus, EF gets an error if declaring a foreign key that is not present in the database?

This how my code will look like:

`

```
public class TableConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration

{
public TableConfiguration(string schema) :
base(schema, "id_d")
{
        HasRequired(x => x.f)
        .WithMany(x => x.Tables)
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.id_f)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        HasRequired(x => x.er)
            .WithMany(x => x.Tables)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.res)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        HasMany(x => x.dc)
            .WithRequired(x => x.Table)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.id_d);

        HasMany(s => s.n)
            .WithRequired(s => s.Table)
            .HasForeignKey(s => s.id_d);
    }
}
}`
```

tks!